# Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' Error in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I have NET Framework 4.7.2 Web Application which was running fine till last week.

Recently I have updated Windows OS. Details:

**Edition:  Windows 10 Enterprise
Version:    21H2
OS build:   19044.1348
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0**

After upgrading the OS, I started to have following issue while launching the WebApplication on IIS Express.

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a
> problem in C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe.
>
> Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The
> address of the error was at 0xc488d19a, on thread 0x57d4. The error
> code is 0xc0000005.  This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the
> unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this
> bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke,  which
> may corrupt the stack.

I don't know how to fix this issue.

If I host the application on IIS it works fine.